# Error in .local(x, ..., value) : unused argument (warn = FALSE) when trying to plot rasterdata

Tags: raster, r, sentinel

I am trying to plot some Sentinel 2 Tif Data.

```
> library(raster)
> 
> # Sentinel 2 Raster Data
> S2_2017_05_B04 <- raster('C:/Users/leona/Desktop/S2/S2_2017_05_B04.tif')
> S2_2017_05_B08 <- raster('C:/Users/leona/Desktop/S2/S2_2017_05_B08.tif')
> S2_2017_05_B04
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 10980, 10980, 120560400  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent     : 3e+05, 409800, 5590200, 5700000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : S2_2017_05_B04.tif 
names      : Grayscale 

> S2_2017_05_B08
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 10980, 10980, 120560400  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent     : 3e+05, 409800, 5590200, 5700000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : S2_2017_05_B08.tif 
names      : Grayscale 

> plot(S2_2017_05_B08, col = gray(0:100 / 100))
Error in .local(x, ..., value) : unused argument (warn = FALSE)
> traceback()
17: `crs<-`(`*tmp*`, warn = FALSE, value = prj)
16: `crs<-`(`*tmp*`, warn = FALSE, value = prj)
15: .fromRasterLayerBrick(from)
14: asMethod(object)
13: methods::as(x, "SpatRaster")
12: rast(x)
11: rast(x)
10: .readCellsGDAL(x, uniquecells, layers)
9: .readCells(x, cells, 1)
8: .cellValues(x, cell)
7: .local(x, size, ...)
6: sampleRegular(object, size = maxpixels, ext = ext, asRaster = TRUE)
5: sampleRegular(object, size = maxpixels, ext = ext, asRaster = TRUE)
4: .plotraster2(x, col = col, maxpixels = maxpixels, add = add, 
       ext = ext, interpolate = interpolate, colNA = colNA, main = main, 
       addfun = addfun, facvar = facvar, alpha = alpha, npretty = npretty, 
       ...)
3: .local(x, y, ...)
2: plot(S2_2017_05_B08, col = gray(0:100/100))
1: plot(S2_2017_05_B08, col = gray(0:100/100))
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] raster_3.6-20 sp_1.6-0     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.3   rgdal_1.6-6      tools_4.1.3      rstudioapi_0.14  Rcpp_1.0.10      codetools_0.2-19 grid_4.1.3      
[8] lattice_0.20-45  terra_1.6-41    
>
```

But I am getting this error message:

```
Error in .local(x, ..., value) : unused argument (warn = FALSE)
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

i updated RStudio, R and all packages and it's working now